# Unity camera render to cache

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with camera. I copy-pasted a example script by Unity3D ([here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.Render.html)) and set up everything. When I called a function to get a Texture2D from camera appeared this error:[image: Error] Some solutions?

Comment: You need to post the code that's causing the error in your question

Comment: Please copy-paste your `assets/ImageGenerator.cs` script into the question and format it as code (`{ }` button)